# How to mark all descendants of all source nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In a directed graph you have source nodes, which have in-degree = 0. I want to do this procedure:

1. Pick one source node
2. For each of its descendants, mark that it is a descendant of the source node, and the number of hops to it. Maybe using breadth first search
3. Repeat 1 until done

I can search for all source nodes, using:

```sql
CALL gds.graph.create( 'RELREV', 'note', {REL: {orientation: 'REVERSE'}});
CALL gds.degree.write('RELREV', { writeProperty: 'indegree' });
MATCH (n) WHERE n.indegree=0;
```

I can mark all the descendants of one source node (say node A), using:

```sql
match p=(start {name: 'nodename'})-[:REL*..8]->(n) 
with n, collect(length(p)) as collect 
unwind collect as hoplist 
with n, collect, min(hoplist) as min 
set n.A=min return n.name, collect, n.A;
```

But I can't find the way to mark this automatically for all the source nodes. Mostly because I don't know how to set a list property names, say property A for source node A, property B for source node B, and so on. I guess [Parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) is the place to start, but reading that it doesn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go along these lines ( not tested BTW), using [apoc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setProperty/) and assuming that you have a set of 'source' nodes.

```
// get paths in an efficient way, so up to a 'leaf'
MATCH p=(source)-[:REL*]->(n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)-[:REL]->())

// create a set of rows for each path. number of rows equals length of path
UNWIND RANGE(1,LENGTH(p)) AS i
WITH source,i,nodes(p)[i] AS descendant 

// use apoc magic  
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(descendant,source.name,i) YIELD node

// check the results
RETURN source.name, properties(node)
```

Additional explanation

- the `WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)-[:REL]->())` is exclude paths that you do not need to investigate . e.g. if you have `(source)-[REL]->(d1)-[REL]->(d2)` , you do not need to investigate `(source)-[REL]->(d1)`
- if you have a graph like image below
  [image]

This part of the query

```
MATCH (source) WHERE source.name CONTAINS 'Ooker'
MATCH p=(source)-[:REL*]->(n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)-[:REL]->())
UNWIND RANGE(1,LENGTH(p)) AS i
WITH source,i,nodes(p)[i] AS descendant 
RETURN source.name, i, descendant.name
```

returns this:

```
╒═════════════╤═══╤═════════════════╕
│"source.name"│"i"│"descendant.name"│
╞═════════════╪═══╪═════════════════╡
│"Ooker2"     │1  │"D"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker2"     │2  │"E"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker2"     │3  │"B"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker2"     │4  │"C"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker"      │1  │"A"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker"      │2  │"B"              │
├─────────────┼───┼─────────────────┤
│"Ooker"      │3  │"C"              │
└─────────────┴───┴─────────────────┘
```

if you feed the source, i and descendant into the apoc call, it sets the right properties.

Comment: but why do we not need to investigate `(source)-[REL]->(d1)`? I guess that's the reason in my first comparison there are so many null value. Also, we can change the matching pattern to `p=shortestpath((source)-[:REL*]->(n)) where n.name<>source.name` to get the shortest length

Comment: @Ooker  as per your item 2. in your OP.. you need to have 'each descendant'. If you have the 'longest path', i.e. the path that ends with a leaf node, you can process all descendants. Feel free to provide another graph example or script to create it for a graph on which the answer does not provide a solution.